# Avoid reusing thread ids in C++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I noticed that based on [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html), Linux reuses the thread ids of terminated threads instead of generating new ones. For some reason, I need to avoid this behavior. How can I make sure that newly created threads, will have a freshly generated thread id instead of reusing the old ones?

(Update for interested people: I'm working on a DNN scheduler for GPU using PyTorch's C++ API, I need to create a new thread to call each layer/operation, and whenever the newly created thread shares the thread id with a terminated thread, I get *CUDNN_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR*. I have reached this after a long time and if I can create threads with unique ids, I might be able to track down the main reason behind this.)

Update 2: POSIX Thread avoids generating new thread ids (thread objects in glibc implementation) as long as there are terminated threads to reuse, I want to avoid this behavior. Maybe somehow deallocating terminated thread would solve this problem. But I don't know how.

Update 3: Based on lines 84-97 in [link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.35.9000/source/htl/pt-alloc.c#L73), Linux tends to reuse previously allocated but terminated threads. Is it somehow possible to deallocate these threads to prevent from reusing previous thread ids?

Comment: @user7860670 The problem is that it does not happen in a long time, it uses terminated thread ids on purpose. Let's say if you create and join a thread in a loop, all instances will have the thread id. As long as there are thread ids belonging to terminated threads, Linux won't generate new ones in a single process. Id range is wide enough that wouldn't be worried about it if it was randomly generated every time. I will update the post about why I need unique thread ids.

Comment: @DanielLangr can you please elaborate how? I don't understand.

Comment: @AmirFakhimBabaei My comment is no longer relevant according to your question update.

Comment: Possibly relevant? https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/33134. There are more posts in the Issues about this error. Have you checked them?

Comment: @DanielLangr CUDNN_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR is a very general error in PyTorch, it happens in different situations (including mine) and it's very difficult to debug. I have been working on this for weeks.

Comment: That seems rather like a bug in whatever library you're using there. Check their bugtracker. As a workaround, don't terminate threads. If they just sleep, they won't bind much CPU and, provided proper cleanup, relatively little memory, too.

Comment: @user7860670 this relates to my Ph.D. thesis and obviously, it's not possible to explain it in a comment. I need to create a new thread for each operation to be able to implement my idea. Let's say that's what I need.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt library issue or whatever, that is the problem that I'm facing right now. I can't avoid terminating threads by making them sleep. I might need to create hundreds of threads in a second. I know there is a problem, but I don't know where. What I am sure of it is that this only happens whenever the new thread has a repeated thread id. Creating threads with unique ids might not be the solution, but it would definitely help me to reach the real solution.

Comment: @super that's not the point. I don't need a thread id in my logic. The libraries I'm using somehow use the thread id of the active thread and raise an error when the thread id is repeated.

Comment: @AmirFakhimBabaei Ok. That's not at all clear from reading your question. Trying to tackle a bug or design flaw in your python library by bending the underlying thread implementation of c++ to your will seems like the completely wrong way to tackle the problem.

Comment: Either that's a bug in the library (as Ulrich suggested,) or else you aren't using it correctly (e.g., failing to "close" something or "release" something before you let a thread die.) Whatever! You _cannot_ control how Linux chooses thread IDs.

Comment: @super I've never mentioned Python. My code is all C++. I'm not trying to bend thread implementation. My question is, is it possible to avoid reusing thread ids? If it's possible, I'm glad to try it. If not, I need to find another way.

Comment: @SolomonSlow nothing fails to close or release. I can't explain details because I'm using CUDA, PyTorch (C++ API), and thread, this combination makes it complicated. Are you sure about this "You cannot control how Linux chooses thread IDs."? If it's true, I don't need to manipulate Linux's way of creating thread ids, I just want to prevent it from using previous ones. I will add "Update 3" to elaborate on this. I'd be happy to see your comment on that. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe "cannot" was too strong. You can always build your own Linux kernel. A Linux thread ID is an index into a table in the kernel, and obviously it would be bad to let the table grow without bound when the number of _live_ threads does not grow. What you could do in your own kernel is add a layer of translation between unique "user" thread IDs and table indices. But I'm a software professional, not an academic. I have seldom encountered any problem where a custom kernel would be acceptable to the client.

Comment: Do you really need to create a new thread for each layer? I don't think you need to create a new thread for each layer. It sounds like cuDNN doesn't like when you create a new thread for each layer, either.

Comment: "I've asked a very clear question here, how can I create threads with unique thread ids. " -- Here's the clear answer: You can't. The reason is that how these IDs are generated is an implementation detail and it happens that on your implementation they are reused. In any case, the guarantee is that the ID is a unique identifier _only_ as long as the thread runs. If it is used as ID beyond that, that is a bug.

Comment: @user253751 For my approach, yes, I need to create a new thread. And, it's now about that, in the normal situation, there is no problem. But, whenever I try to change the CUDA Context using the "cuCtxSetCurrent" function, this happens. It happens even inside the main thread even if I don't create threads. Seems like PyTorch or maybe CUDNN requires a one-by-one mapping between thread id and CUDA Contexts, which means, that each thread id, is not supposed to run using more than 1 CUDA context. The first time is OK, but the second time I try to change the context, this error happens.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt by unique I mean unique compared to even the terminated threads in the same process. It is unique for live threads and as long as I have not terminated a thread, everything is fine.

Comment: @user253751 and by the second time I mean second time using the same thread id. It might happen in the same thread, or another thread created later but using a thread id belonging to a previously terminated thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be a way to avoid the stack allocation for terminated threads to be reused, you will have to self-allocate the stack memories. The `pthread_attr_setstack` could help. Notice that it add complexity to handle the buffer overflowed and the responsibilities now belong to API users

Following is some tests that I have made by play arround the POSIX thread library

```
Created thread id: 139938008069888 in __pthread_create_2
Created thread id: 139937999677184 in __pthread_create_2
Created thread id: 139937999677184 in __pthread_create_2
Created thread id: 139938008069888 in __pthread_create_2

Thread 1 : db42f700
Thread 2 : dac2e700
Thread 3 : dac2e700
Thread 4 : db42f700
```

As result, the stack is preserved for thread 3,4

With the self-allocated stack

```
Created thread id: 139891916830464 in __pthread_create_2
Set stackaddr to 139891916849184
Set stacksize to 32768
Created thread id: 139891916879616 in __pthread_create_2
Set stackaddr to 139891916898352
Set stacksize to 32768
Created thread id: 139891916928768 in __pthread_create_2
Set stackaddr to 139891916947520
Set stacksize to 32768
Created thread id: 139891916977984 in __pthread_create_2
Thread 1 : 139891916830464
Thread 2 : 139891916879616
Thread 3 : 139891916928768
Thread 4 : 139891916977984
```

Comment: This is interesting, and it may well be useful to the OP.  It should be noted, however, that although `pthread_attr_setstack` is standardized by POSIX, the association between thread stack and thread ID shown here is an undocumented Linux implementation detail.